# SharePoint server 2013 license

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation

I am going to install SharePoint 2013 server in my corporation, I am going to use two tiers:

- Web server and application server on the same physical server.
- Database server on another physical server.

The users in SharePoint server will be get from active directory domain server.

The users will sign in to SharePoint server just from the corporation intranet network.

During this progress I have some questions about:

1. What is the cost of SharePoint 2013 enterprise server license and how can I get it?
2. What is the business CAL for users and do I need it?
3. Can I upgrade the SharePoint version to updated versions like SharePoint 2015..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have some answers:

You have to decide if this is an internet public facing site first or an intranet employee user site first. For public facing, no CAL are needed just the server license. For internal employee sites, you have to have a CAL and that also depends if you are using SharePoint Standard or SharePoint Enterprise as Enterprise needs both CALs/costs more per person.

I am not sure if you have to purchase the "Microsoft Enterprise Agreement" which I think is an annual fee if you want to be able to upgrade to 2015 for free when it comes out. Otherwise I don't think it is just free to upgrade when it comes out.

I would call CDW or MSFT to get a per server price and ask them for specific details to be honest.

I think you can buy SharePoint and each CAL directly from MSFT or a reseller like CDW:

https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/MS-MBL-SHAREPT-SRV-2013/2894673.aspx?RecommendedForEDC=00000001&RecoType=RS&cm_sp=Search-_-Session&ProgramIdentifier=3